# Linking IDataErrorInfo to an existing data model class in a seperate class

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding

I have an existing data model class that cannot be changed, in this example it is named customer. I now need to add data handling using IDataErrorInfo in a different class but cannot seem to work out how to join the 2 classes. What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Class Customer
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private _firstName As String

    Public Property FirstName As String
        Get
            Return _firstName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _firstName = value
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName")
        End Set
    End Property
```

My Error handler looks like this:

```
Public Class CustomerValidation
    Inherits Customer
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo

Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(columnName As String) As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Item
    Get
        Dim errorMessage As String = String.Empty
        Select Case columnName
            Case "FirstName"
                If Customer IsNot Nothing AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(Customer.FirstName) Then
                    errorMessage = "First Name Must Be At Least 1 Character"
                End If
        End Select
        Return errorMessage
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property [Error] As String Implements IDataErrorInfo.Error
    Get
        Return String.Empty
    End Get
End Property
```

I then declare and bind to it like this:

```
   Private _customer As CustomerValidation = New CustomerValidation

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        _customer.FirstName = "Steve"
        Me.DataContext = _customer
```

Comment: Where is the implementation of `IDataErrorInfo`? Specifically the `Error` and `Item[]` properties? Where are they set?

Comment: They are in the CustomerValidation as now shown above